# Prevent automatic restart of failed container to log in for debugging purposes

Tags: docker, minikube

I am deploying container in minikube environment but it fails when starting up, so the pod goes into CrashLoopBackOff status and then stays offline.
It would really help if pod would not be automatically restarted so that I could log into its shell, see some internal logs, debug environment variables etc. How could I achieve this so that I can log into failed container inside pod?
So I want to do something like:

`kubectl exec -it <POD_NAME> -- /bin/bash`

But this works only if pod is in Running status.

Comment: please use kubectl logs <pod> to see the logs, it will you details on how the pod is failed.

Comment: It some cases it can also be helpful to `docker run` the same container locally.  In both plain Docker and Kubernetes, the container/pod exits when the main process exits, so your other option is some kind of wrapper that will keep running, but you'll have to notice events like this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `pod` is failing you should check events and logs.

- Logs can be checked by `kubectl logs <pod_name>`
- Events can be checked by `kubectl get events <pod_name>`

I would also recommend reading [Debug Pods and ReplicationControllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-pod-replication-controller/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no way to achieve what I asked for, so have to use other debugging techniques. Thank you for answers!